# Magento installation

Tags: magento

I had installed Magento successfully , but when I try the checkout, it always display a "product not found".

Even if I try to click to any product to get a product details, it always not able to display a product..

I take it that the database configuration and details were correct during installation otherwise it won't allow the successful installation..

Comment: I sort it out... It is a cache problem.

I do a re-index as recommended by the system when I logged in as admin.. Once the re-indexing is done, the catalogue works fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve 404 not found problem in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872844/how-to-solve-404-not-found-problem-in-magento)

Answer (score 1):

[redcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279079/redcoder), the OP, already self-answered the question.

Quote:

---

I sorted it out... It is a cache problem.

I do a reindex as recommended by the system when I'm logged in as admin.. Once the reindexing is done, the catalogue works fine.

---

<sub>Note: It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. Please just post it as an real answer, but *not* in a question or comment. Posting as real answer helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear (avoids making other people wasting their time).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You made the mistake that you installed the Magento after the media SQL files are inserted.

Please follow the below procedure for displaying the products:

1. Create the database named Magento and download the Magento from the website http://www.magentocommerce.com/download and extract inside the localhost(var\www)
2. Download the sample data from the website http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. Extract the tar/zip and place the media folder inside the Magento downloaded folder.
4. The extracted sample data contains the SQL file where the all SQL statements are copied and run in the magento database.
5. After that only the Magento installation has to be carried out.