# How to solve 404 not found problem in Magento

Tags: magento

I have installed full release Magento on localhost from  `http://www.magentocommerce.com/download`. Before doing installation I have created a database and import Magento sample database (downloaded from Magento site).

After that continue installation process. When I checked fronted  its shows `Best Selling Products` when I clicked any of the product it gives error given below:

```
Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

        * If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
        * If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
What can you do?

    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Demo Store.

        * Go back to the previous page.
        * Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
        * Follow these links to get you back on track!
          Store Home
          My Account
```

I am new to Magento.

Comment: is mod_rewrite active in your server?

Comment: What software do you use for your localhost webserver? Is it apache or something else? If it is apache, please check that mod_rewrite and AllowOverride is set to All for your document root.

Comment: @ Ivan Chepurny Its apache and using ubuntu

Comment: @ Ivan Chepurny Its necessary to enable mod_rewrite on localhost?

Comment: mod_rewrite not enable on my localhost.I have checked this using<? phpInfo(); ?> In Load Modules mod_rewrite not appear.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've experienced this too. In the admin go to *System > Index Management* and rebuild the various catalog indexes, especially the URL rewrites.

This is because the sample data doesn't have it's paths stored to begin with, it needs to be calculated, and the Best Selling Products section doesn't read the actual paths in use, instead it is a Static CMS Block with it's HREFs fixed. This will probably never occur for products you enter yourself so it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I need your help because I am new in magento.Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Wamp. I had my folder named Magento, renaming it to magento, fixed the problem. (Lower case)

Comment: Me too, Just change as per your idea( Magento to magento). It's working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I was transferring Magento from a Unix server to a Windows server. My issue was to do with links looking like this (not working)

http://www.magentoshop.com.au/shop/product01.html

instead of

http://www.magentoshop.com.au/shop/index.php/product01.html

Haven't worked out how to fix all links yet, but just adding it tells me where the issue lies. Hope it helps someone else.