# Magento installation Problem in plesk

Tags: magento

I have installed magento from Plesk,The home is well,with layout buy when I click any link it show "Not Found" message.
I can not figure out the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve 404 not found problem in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872844/how-to-solve-404-not-found-problem-in-magento) or [Magento installation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2379722/471559)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with Apache mod_rewrite.

Anyway, you can check is it true. Let's just say that you where going to open http://www.example.com/electronics and got 404. Ok, no panic. Try to edit URL to be like this: http://www.example.com**/index.php**/electronics 
If it works, than definitely you have a troubles with one of the following:

1. Apache mod_rewrite is not enabled. If you can open a page with phpinfo(), you may try to search "mod_rewrite" on that page. No results found -- no mod_rewrite... Call your hosting support.
2. You need to set RewriteBase directive in your .htaccess file (it may be hidden for web based filemanager). By default the line with RewriteBase is commented, and you can uncomment it and leave it's default value "/" if your Magento is uploaded to document root. If your Magento is in some sub-directory under document root, you need to set RewriteBase value lie this "/my_folder_with_magento".